# How to create UIView to show text like in Terminal?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I'm making telnet program and I have everything resolved but the text output.
I want it to have console look and feel, and basic controls like UITextField or UILabel do not work at all for this.
Is there any custom control to do this?
How can I write one myself?

Comment: Hi @Dvole , I am also facing the same problem, I have resolved everything except console View,  so finally what you used to make this console look and feel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use UITextView to display text and UITextField to input the text and override textFieldShouldReturn: method:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {

    NSString* inputString = textField.text;
    [inputString lowercaseString];

    // when you type 'clear' clear output view
    if ([inputString isEqualToString:@"clear"])
    {
         // Your text view outlet to display the data
        [self.outputTextView clear];
    }

    else
    {
        [self.outputTextView setText:inputString concatenate:YES];
        // Your text field outlet to input the data
        [self.inputTextField setText:@""];
    return YES;
}
```

Remember to set up text field delegate for input text field.

Comment: Hi @Greg , i am little bit confuse why you are using  UITextView and UITextFields. Please explain me.

Comment: @SumitGarg UITextField is the one line 'place' where you can enter the console commands. UITextView is much bigger and it's read only 'place' where I display the commands with the results ( it also contains the previous commands).

Comment: @Grey Thanks, but my problem do not solve with this concept because  i have only one UITextView in which both output and command are displayed. I just want to implement the same Terminal like screen that Mac has.

Comment: @Grey I am also set attributedString in UITextField. it will work perfectly except take time . can you provide me some suggestion to improve the performance.